# Имитация клика по input type file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-file-upload

Доброго времени суток, проблема заключается в том что, когда кликаешь по кнопке первый раз, инпут через ajax сработает, и загрузит файл, а вот если кликнишь второй раз без перезагрузки страници, ничего не произойдёт.

```
<div class="fileinput-button">
                    <a id="fileLinkUpload"><span style="margin: 70px;"><mi:text>Browse...</mi:text></span></a>
                    <div></div>
                    <input type="file" id="StoreLogoImageUploader" name="StoreLogoImageUploader"/>
                </div>
```

JS код для обработки

```
    var wrapper = $( ".fileinput-button" ),
    inp = wrapper.find( "input" ),
    btn = wrapper.find( "#fileLinkUpload" ),
    lbl = wrapper.find( "div" );

btn.add( lbl ).click(function(){
    inp.click();
});
```

Comment: наверное вы имеете в виду, что у вас не открывается окно для загрузки файлов при клике на кнопку Browse? Если нет, то где код с ajax?

Comment: @Mit9l окно открывается, но после выбора уже ничего не происходит.

Comment: закиньте пример на jsfiddle

Comment: вообще вам как вариант можно обойтись без триггера (если конечно у вас нет никаких ограничений в этом плане) -  `<label for="fileLinkUpload"><span style="margin: 70px;"><mi:text>Browse...</mi:text></span></label>`  оберните кнопку в `label`